# How to connect DIP switch in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, 7segmentdisplay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftSnBn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to make a BCD to 7 segment decoder, but I can't make it work. I have a 7 segment with a common anode and I have connected a 1 kΩ resistor to each one of its segments.

I am using a 9V battery to power it.

- How should I connect the DIP switch in the circuit?

Also, in the circuit, when I try to test my ICs (74LS32 and 74LS08), by connecting the ground to the inputs and  output to a LED light, but it's not working properly.
All of my 7408 ICs are only producing a high output when both inputs from switches are off, and when one or two are on, it will have a low output, while my 7432 ICs are acting like AND gate (only high output when both inputs are high).
I have tested the same ICs on a digital trainer and it was working fine, but when I try to put it in my circuit, it's back to not working properly.
What could have I possibly done wrong?

Comment: where does the DIP switch suddenly come from? Why 1kΩ? You're using ICs, but you're not telling us how you've connected them. So, I'm sorry, you'll have learn to use the schematic editor that is built-in to this very site in the question editor. We can't help you on  a basis of "I can't show you what is connected, how it's connected, but it's not working, help!".

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, I did not know that there's a schematic editor. I'm using the stack exchange android app.

Comment: @brhans I have already fixed my post

Comment: Just so we're clear - you do *not* have any pull-up or pull-down resistors on the inputs to your logic gates do you? And I'm guessing that you have applied power to the correct pins on your logic ICs?

Comment: @brhans No, I don't have any resistors connected to the inputs and I have connected the power to the correct pins of my ICs.

Comment: We also need to know what you mean by "but it's not working properly". What did you do to the switches, what result did you expect, what result did you observe?

Comment: I'm guessing that lack of pullup resistors is the problem.

Comment: @brhans all of my 7408 ICs are only producing a high output when both inputs from switches are off, and when one or two are on, it will have a low output, while my 7432 ICs are acting like AND gate (only high output when both inputs are high). I have tested the same ICs on a digital trainer and it was working fine, but when I try to put it in my circuit, it's back to not working properly.

Comment: Please add that information to your question; generally, add as much info as you can!

Comment: Please specify: are 7408 and 7432 the _exact_ markings on the chips, or do they say 74LS08/74LS32 or 74HC08/74HC32 or something else?

Comment: A 9V battery will kill 74 and 74LS chips. They're only designed to run from 5V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your schematic, it appears that you think that a TTL input that is not connected high automatically goes low.  This is incorrect.  A TTL input should *never* be left floating.  For your circuit to work correctly, each input that is floating when its switch is open needs a resistor to ground.  For standard TTL, the resistor must be 470 ohms or smaller.  Common values are 220 ohms and 330 ohms.

Your schematic does notshow power and ground connections to the logic chips.  Do you have the Vcc and GND pins connected?

AND

The TTL parts you mention cannot run on 9 V.  They are strictly limited to 5 V supply voltage.

Comment: Yes, my logic chips have their Vcc and GND connected. Thank you. I will change the the supply voltage to 5V and add resistors to the switches.

Comment: @user75283 Note that this does mean that your chips are fried since you connected them to 9V power, and you need to get new ones.

Comment: @Hearth is it possible for them to still work? I have tried them on a 5V power supply after connecting to the 9V and they are still working fine

Comment: @user75283 It's possible, yeah. I'm surprised they still work, though. If they're not actually the TTL version (74C series for example, but not 74 or 74LS or even 74HC) it's possible they could work on higher voltages and be fine.

Comment: The OP's schematic shows the switches connected to Ground/negative.  If he is using 74LS parts, no resistors are required on the inputs, as an unconnected TTL input will appear as a High (but pull-up resistors of 5 K or so are still a Good Thing)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHT6KD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Serial In line resistor packs exist to make this easy.

Note TTL logic 7432 and 7408 needs 5V and will be killed by 9 volts, but you already know that from the answer to your [question about why your chips didn't work](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/419007/7432-and-7408-ics-not-working-properly/419021#419021).

(If you're using real TTL and not modern HC CMOS versions you can omit the pull-up resistors R1-R4)

Comment: R1 appears to be useless.

Comment: How do I know if the ICs that I am using are TTL or HC CMOS versions?

Comment: @user75283 If they're marked exactly as "7432", they are TTL. If marked as "74HC32", they're CMOS. Other technologies and thus other markings exist as well.

Comment: @Hearth it's exactly as useless as SW1, but I'm not aware of people making 4 pin, SIL 3 resistor packs.

Comment: @james Fair point. For the sake of completeness (and because I went to look out of curiosity), they do actually [make those](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bourns-inc/4604X-101-103LF/4604X-101-103LF-ND/3593680), but they're certainly not a part you'd encounter very often, and probably no cheaper than having the extra resistor anyway.

Comment: Inputs on bipolar TTL parts (74xx, 74LS, 74AS, and others without a "C" in the middle) will appear as High with no connection, so pull-up resistors aren't usually required (but still Good Practice).  CMOS parts (74C, 74HC, others with a "C") have very high impedance inputs, and REQUIRE a pull-up resistor to ensure the inputs appear as High with no other connection.  It is important to specify the exact part you are using.  Also, as mentioned, bipolar TTL has an absolute maximum voltage rating of 7 volts.  Some CMOS versions can accept higher voltages.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're having a bit of trouble putting your logic chips to work, I should point out that there's a good source of documentation for these guys: datasheets.

<s>Google</s> Search online for the codes written on top of the component and add the word "datasheet". Look for a PDF from a reputable IC manufacturer (preferably the one who produced your component).

For example, "74LS32 datasheet" leads me to a PDF from Texas Instruments that says:

> absolute maximum ratings (...)
> Supply voltage, VCC (see Note1) ... 7 V

And later on:

> recommended operating conditions
> Vcc Supply voltage ... 4.5 ... 5 ... 5.5 (min nom max)

That says that, if your IC has 74LS32 written on it, a 9 V power supply isn't a good thing.

And no, I'm not telling you to RTFM, it's just that datasheets are your friends. =)